# How to find the recent date from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1:

```
ID  | Date

001 | 02/05/2011
001 | 02/08/2012
001 | 01/09/2012
002 | 08/02/2009
...
```

I want to select most recent date for each `id`.

I tried the query:

```
Select top1 from table1
```

Expected Output

```
001 01/09/2012
002 08/02/2009
...
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id, max([date]) 
from [table]
group by id
```